# Sencha Architect for EXT JS displays error pop up on grid column' Renderer

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, extjs4.2, sencha-architect

I am working with EXT JS grid. I am using Sencha Architect version 2.2.2 
I am calling a function from inside the renderer function of the grid column but it is throwing function undefined error while I am clicking on the Tab Panel which is parent to the grid in discussion.

The grid columns have renderer function, which inturn calls another function as below.

```
       xtype: 'gridcolumn',
           renderer: function(value, metaData, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store, view) {
             myCalledMethod();
            },
```

I am getting this error on Sencha Architect. However, it works correctly and there is not error on firebug console.

```
An error occurred while executing this function 'renderer'
'myCalledMethod' is not defined.
```

[image]

I have declared this method before the grid is painted. 
I was referring to the sencha forums and found that it is a known issue. 
Reference : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?186674-Adding-renderer-to-a-grid-column-designer-shows-an-error&langid=14

Please note, I am getting this error while I am clicking on that form in Sencha Architect.
I verified couple of times that there is no issue with the scope where the function is defined.
I am declaring the function well ahead before the grid is rendered.

Any help would be great.

Thanks,

Comment: The link you posted refers to the previous version of Architect. I this an architect question? Which Ext version? Also, I cannot see where is myCalledMethod defined so it may really not be available when renderer runs.

Comment: Please add the context in which this grid is defined, and `myCalledMethod` is defined. It may be that `myCalledMethod` isn't in scope when you call it. Or, you might need to prepend it with `this`, as in: `this.myCalledMethod()`. But we need more of your code to help further.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Please note, the code is executed fine but the error is appearing only while I click on this page on Sencha Architect. There is no error on the FireFox debugger